# Leaflet | No se muestra el label dentro del polígono

Tags: javascript, leaflet

No se muestra la etiqueta o label en el centro del polígono:
(El polígono sí se muestra pero el label no)

**Código:**

```
  var cuencas = L.polygon([
    [51.509, -0.08],
    [51.503, -0.06],
    [51.51, -0.047]
],{
    color: 'yellow',
    fillColor: ' #cecf6c',
    fillOpacity: 0.5
}).addTo(map);


var label = new L.Label();
  label.setContent("Zona 10");
  label.setLatLng(polygon.getBounds().getCenter());
  map.showLabel(label);
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Leaflet estás utilizando? `L.Label` ya está [deprecado](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label#leafletlabel) desde la versión 1.0 de Leaflet.

Comment: utilizo la versión 1.7.1 https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como mencionaba en el comentario, `L.Label` ya no se utiliza desde la versión 1.0 de Leaflet; el [repositorio](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label#leafletlabel) muestra el siguiente mensaje:

> NOTA: a partir de Leaflet 1.0, `L.Label` se añade al núcleo de Leaflet como `L.Tooltip` y este plugin queda obsoleto.

Por lo tanto, para mostrar un label/tooltip (código en base al proporcionado en la pregunta):

```js
let map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

let cuencas = L.polygon([
  [51.509, -0.08],
  [51.503, -0.06],
  [51.51, -0.047]
], {
  color: 'yellow',
  fillColor: ' #cecf6c',
  fillOpacity: 0.5
}).addTo(map);

//######## nótese que en este caso la diferencia es mínima: L.tooltip en lugar de L.Label
label = L.tooltip({permanent: true}); //permanent:true se encarga de mostrar el tooltip en todo momento 
label.setContent("Zona 10");
label.setLatLng(cuencas.getBounds().getCenter());
cuencas.bindTooltip(label);
//########
```

```css
#map {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Las opciones, eventos y métodos que maneja este objeto pueden verse en la [documentación](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#tooltip).

Comment: Muchas gracias. Se muestra la etiqueta al colocar el mouse sobre el mismo perfectamente. ¿Cómo se haría para que se visualice en todo momento incluso cuando no se coloca el mouse sobre el mismo? Gracias!

Comment: Modifiqué el código para mostrar lo que preguntaste @ret. De nuevo, en la documentación encontrarás más opciones :)

Comment: Muchas gracias! Funciona perfecto. ; )